# Django; Can't display on main page notes from admin page

Tags: python, django

I'm creating my first Django notes app and I'm trying to insert and display notes on the main page. Unfortunately I managed only how to insert them in data base, but I can't display them on the main page.

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Note
from .forms import NoteForm

def home(request):
    notes = Note.objects
    template = loader.get_template('note.html')
    form = NoteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()

    context = {'notes': notes, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'note.html', context)
```

And here is my html file:

```
<link href="http://codepen.io/edbond88/pen/CcgvA.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
            body {<br />
              background: rgba(222,222,222,1);<br />
              margin: 20px;<br />
            }<br />
</style>
<h1>Notes App</h1>


<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
<input type="submit" value="Add note">
</form>
```

I'm trying to make the app from this tutorial: https://pythonspot.com/django-tutorial-building-a-note-taking-app/

Answer (score 1):

You need `Note.objects.all()` instead of `Note.objects` in **views.py**:

```
def home(request):
    notes = Note.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('note.html')
    form = NoteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()

    context = {'notes': notes, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'note.html', context)
```

and also, you need to iterate over them to show them in the template:

```
<h1>Notes App</h1>

{% for note in notes %}
    <p>{{ note }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
return render(request, 'note.html', context=context)
```

instead of this :

```
return render(request, 'note.html', context)
```

and this :

```
notes = Note.objects.all()
```

instead of this :

```
notes = Note.objects
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you didn't add any action into your form. The `action` attribute should be the view where you want to submit the form to.

So this is what you should do first:

```
<h1>Notes App</h1>

<form method="POST" action="whatever_your_url_for_this_page_is">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <input type="submit" value="Add note">
</form>
```